# In flink how to verify if same user data is not received in the given window?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a IOT device emitting data to kafka topic , data like firstname,lastname,emailId,event_time etc .
I have to  Verify no other event received for the same user in the defined Window of operation for the stream processing.
For example if i am getting user X details 3 times within a window of 5 min , I should process(add to sink) only first data received from the user X and next two records to be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution will be to key the events by user data and reduce them leaving only the first one.

Something like this:

```java
dataStream
    .keyBy(event -> event.emailId()) // Key by emailId
    .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Event>() {
        @Override
        public Integer reduce(Event value1, Event value2)
         throws Exception {
            return event1; // always leave only first event
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out , how to ensure if events for same user in coming in same window?

Comment: keyBy guarantees that all events with the same key will be processed by the same task.